# Cordova doesn't show image in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I try to develop a cordova project for cross-platforms. I have to upload photos to a server from gallery or with camera. And also i should show their thumbnails or small previews.

Gallery and camera option works in browser but in android when i try to select and image and upload. It uploads but doesn't show little image.

Thanks.

It's  [my html](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23383173/)

And [my javascript code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23383181/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FileTransfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) object provides a way to upload files using an HTTP multi-part POST or PUT request, and to download files.To install this plugin simply run Command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Properties

> onprogress: Called with a ProgressEvent whenever a new chunk of data
>   is transferred. (Function)

Methods

> upload: Sends a file to a server.
>
> download: Downloads a file from server.
>
> abort: Aborts an in-progress transfer.

Read about the FileTransfer you will get their example code of upload file and download file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was using ng-file-upload and i go on with it. I thought maybe a solution is exist about that. But i think i'll go with FileTransfer. Thanks again :)